# Invalid token when i try to confirm e-mail, ASP .NET Core 6 Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

I'm struggling for the confirmation of the e-mail in ASP.Net Core 6.
I'm using userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync for confirm the email that I want to validate,
Recently I unset the encoding of the confirmation's token, even if I removed I still get the invalid token.

This is how i created the token for confirmation

```
var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(newUser);
var confirmationLink = Url.Link("email-confirmation", new { token, inputUserModel.EmailUser });
```

And this is for acquire the token

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("ConfirmEmail")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string token, string email)
        {
            if (token == null || email == null) return StatusCode(406, new { message = "You need to provide the informations", DateTime.Now });

            var emailController = new EmailAddressAttribute();

            if (!emailController.IsValid(email)) return StatusCode(406, new { message = "The information provided is not an email address.", DateTime.Now });

            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

            if (user == null) return NotFound( new { message = "The email you provide is not assigned to any users.", DateTime.Now });

            if (await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)) return StatusCode(401, new { message = "Your email is already confirmed", DateTime.Now });

            var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                user.EmailConfirmed = true;
                await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            }

            return (result.Succeeded ? Ok(new { message = $"the {_dataHelper.CriptEmail(email)} is been confirmed.", DateTime.Now }) : NotFound(new { message = "The token you provide was not found.", DateTime.Now }));
        }
```

Tell me if you need something else.

P.S. `_dataHelper.CriptEmail` it's a method made by me for soft encode the email, something like `(an\*\*\*\*@gmail.com)`

I'm expecting that the confirmation works, by a correct suggest.

Any kind of help is accepted :)

Comment: Try to compare your generated and incoming token. In past I encountered with issue where symbol '+' in generated token was replaced with another symbol in incoming token. It can be similar problem

Comment: Possibly an error in your data protection configuration. Examples: no persistence of keys, or multiple server instances and each instance has its own keys.

Comment: GMAIL will not work with [AllowAnonymous].  There must be an account and you must use a windows credential.  Also the From property in the email must match the user in the credentials.  Email will refuse a connection with username and password.  See following : https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

Answer (score 1):

For any of you coming in here, and still not finding the solution (and checking the tokens which are identical), then you might be as blunt as me and have set the generated token with `GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync` instead of using the right method: `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync`..

Comment: I was using GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync() instead of GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync() because I'm super observant, ty

Answer (score 0):

this happened for me and i don't know why but "+" were replaced with " " after reading from url.

so i did this and it worked for me

```
token.replace(" ", "+");
```